# How to understand when the user has changed the subject in a conversation?

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I am using LangChain for a chat bot. I have managed to create the prompt and send the chat history in it. A problem I am facing is that when the user is talking about a certain topic for some time and then starts another, the LM is unable to understand the change of subject. How do I make it understand? Is there a tuned LLM for this or an agent?

```
recommender = VertexAI(model_name="text-bison@001",
           max_output_tokens=1024,
           temperature=0.9)
conv_memory = ConversationStringBufferMemory(
    input_key="input_text",
    buffer=user.chat_history,
    memory_key="chat_history"
)
conversation = ConversationChain(
        llm=recommender,
        prompt=prompt,
        input_key="input_text",
        memory=conv_memory
)
llm_response: str = conversation.predict(input_text = input_text)
```

Comment: could you please elaborate what do you mean by subject here, in the chat context it will be text in and text out and I believe single sentence may have multiple subjects..

Comment: @ZKS As the LLM does not hold any context, we are sending the chat history in the prompt. When the user and LLM have been chatting on a topic, then the user changes it. how to know this has happened? Is there any Agent or LLM for this?

Comment: Ok, you need to then drive the whole chat and understand route the user is taking while chatting. Like orthodox nlp chatbot way. Because while chat is in progress it would be difficult to understand the topic from the unambiguous sentences. We can definitely have model running behind the scene to predict the keywords from sentences however it would come with expense of poor customer experience.